# How do I restart an index.js file in a Ghost install?

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost

I incorrectly used my console to "forever stop index.js" in an installation of Ghost.  Now the site is offline.  How do I fix this?

Comment: `forever start index.js` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

From the Ghost help support:

> To start Ghost using `forever` from the Ghost installation directory
>   type
>   `NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js`

http://support.ghost.org/deploying-ghost/